# Extending an java abstract class with clojure (java.lang.Classloader)

Tags: clojure

Is there any way of extending an abstract class in clojure? I wish to extend the java.lang.Classloader in clojure. Is there a good way to get a subclass of the Classloader object without going back into java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to extend an abstract class in Clojure is to use `:gen-class` directive in the `ns` form or `(gen-class)` macro. For example:

```
(ns example.core
  (:gen-class
     :extends ClassLoader
     :name example.CustomClassLoader))

(defn -findClass [this name]
  (println "example.findClass")
  nil)
```

AOT compilation must be used in order for `(gen-class)` to have any effect. See [(gen-class)](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/gen-class) in Clojure API documentation.

Note: this approach has already been suggested by A. Webb in a comment to another answer.

Comment: Can this extended class now be used by Java code? I mean could it be that the Java code would not be aware that it is dealing with a  Clojure created class versus a Java created class?

Comment: Short answer is yes. The compiled class is bytecode and it does not matter which compiler generated it. The tricky part is that the generated class depends on Clojure. So the library has to be AOT compiled and Clojure has to be in the CLASSPATH.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Provide the abstract class to the proxy macro, like this:

```
(-> (proxy [ClassLoader] []
      (findResource [name]
        (java.net.URL. "http://somewhere")))
    (.findResource "doot"))

--> #object[java.net.URL 0x75dc3e1d "http://somewhere"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what do you mean by:

> without going back into java

However, in Clojure you can use [proxy macro](http://clojure.org/java_interop#Java%20Interop-Implementing%20Interfaces%20and%20Extending%20Classes-%28%20proxy%20%5Bclass-and-interfaces%5D%20%5Bargs%5D%20fs+%29) which it is part of Clojure Java Interop toolkit.

In your REPL:

> (doc proxy)
>
> Expands to code which creates a instance of a proxy class that implements the named class/interface(s) by calling the supplied fns. A single class, if provided, must be first. If not provided it defaults to Object. The interfaces names must be valid interface types. If a method fn is not provided for a class method, the superclass method will be called. If a method fn is not provided for an interface method, an UnsupportedOperationException will be thrown should it be called. Method fns are closures and can capture the environment in which proxy is called. Each method fn takes an additional implicit first arg, which is bound to this. Note that while method fns can be provided to override protected methods, they have no other access to protected members, nor to super, as these capabilities cannot be proxied.

Comment: I don't _think_ this would work because proxy does not allow you to call protected methods, e.g. `defineClass`. I think you'd want to use the `gen-class` facility.